# Resize JPanel with a line separator

Tags: java, swing, resize, panel, separator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making a JPanel manually resizable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119989/making-a-jpanel-manually-resizable)

I am doing a chat program with javaswing and I would like to create a separator that can adjust the dimension of 2 pannels "

[image]

The black line could reduce the height of the top panel and increase the bottom one.

How this is possiblle ? What layout sould I use ? Thank you very much.

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

Try [JSplitPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html).

[How to use SplitPanes?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html)

[Examples of JSplitPane](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/JSplitPane.htm)

Comment: [OT] it took me some time to find it is called a Sash in SWT.