# Java Swing, how to make a JPanel resizable with mouse?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I have been developing an user interface with Java Swing, and I have met a problem in JPanel resizing.

This is my problem: I would like to let a JPanel be resizable by the user, when the user points its mouse over the JPanel border line (as described in the following figure). Now, if I move my mouse over that line, nothing happens. I would like that I could change its size with my mouse.

[image: Interface resizing problem]

Here's my code portion:

```
    JTabbedPane _tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
JPanel gridAndCommandPaneValidation = new JPanel(); 
    gridAndCommandPaneValidation.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 

    ValidationTableModel vtm = new ValidationTableModel(new LinkedList<DatabaseAnalysisValues>());
    tableValidation = new JTable(vtm);
    JScrollPane scrollpaneVal = new JScrollPane(tableValidation);

 tableValidation.setAutoscrolls(true);
    gridAndCommandPaneValidation.add(scrollpaneVal, BorderLayout.WEST);
    gridAndCommandPaneValidation.add(getKBestValidationCommandsPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
    _tabbedPane.add("Validation", gridAndCommandPaneValidation);
```

Is there anyone that can help me?

Many thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html).

Comment: why dont you place it inside a JSplitPane and let user drag the divider ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a JPanel manually resizable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119989/making-a-jpanel-manually-resizable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [`JSplitPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html) and the corresponding [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html). This component can do exactly what you want and it behaves very well. Try the first example in the tutorial, you'll see.